# MySql query: difficulties to record a field with amount containing decimals

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

Added - Solved: My code was good right from the start, the issue was the Currency used, If it was USD, it would have work as is. My test was done with CAD currency, and for that, "amount_gross" returned an empty value (doc from Paypal), had to use "mc_gross" - working for all currencies!

So proper code working for ALL currencies would be :

```
$item_name = $_POST['item_name']; 
$item_number = $_POST['item_number']; 
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status']; 
$payment_amt = $_POST['mc_gross'];          // instead of payment_gross !!!
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id']; 
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom']; 
if ($payment_status == 'Completed') { ....
```

Thanks all for your help!!!

--- end of added ---

I have a final issue in my project, (Paypal integration): After Ipn sent "Complete", I like to save data to MySQL, but I have a problem with the field "payment_amt".

When the amount has no decimals (ex:100) it works, with decimal (ex:100.34), payment_amt is not recorded. All other fields are recorded. It has to do with parameters I have to add, althought I have difficulties understanding the logic (I am not a programmer). Thank you for your help.

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO al_paypal
(item_name,item_number,payment_status,payment_amt,txn_id,payer_email,custom,commerce_id)
       VALUES (
       '". $item_name ."',
       '". $item_number ."', 
       '". $payment_status ."',
       '". $payment_amt ."',  // does not record if amount has decimals
       '". $txn_id ."',
       '". $payer_email ."',
       '". $custom ."',
       '". $commerce_id ."'
        )"); 
    }
$item_name = $_POST['item_name']; // restaurant
$item_number = $_POST['item_number']; // my ordernymber
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status']; //should be Completed
$payment_amt = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id']; // Paypal transaction number
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom']; 
if ($payment_status == 'Completed') { ....
```

Here is more code

Below :

```
 $payment_amt = "33,56";  // if I use this it records properly
 $payment_amt = $_POST['payment_gross']; // if I use this it records 0
 // if I use (as suggested) ". $payment_amt .",  instead of: '". $payment_amt ."',  Nothing records at all.
 $payment_amt  = preg_replace("/,/", '.', $payment_amt);
 $payment_amt =  number_format($payment_amt, 2, '.', '');
```

Very hard to understand what is wrong. Cannot use errors, since it is IPN, it runs when Paypal sends something.

I checked if

```
  $payment_amt = $_POST['payment_gross'];
```

and it does (I have the amount sent via text msg).

```
 $headersCell = 'From: "" <"' . $_POST['payment_gross']. '">'. "\r\n". "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
 mail($emailtoCell, $subjectCell, $textCell, $headersCell);
```

Weird. I give up for tonight.

Comment: You do not need quotes around decimal values in your query. It could be causing a problem? Try `" . floatval($payment_amt) . ",` also what MySQL type is that column? Does any value get inserted?

Comment: What is your PHP script's locale, particularly the decimal point character?  See output of [`localeconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php).  You ought to consider using [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to obtain a literal value in a format that MySQL recognises.

Comment: For debugging, I recommend you create the SQL text into a variable, and echo the contents of that variable before you execute it.  e.g. `$sql = "INSERT ... ";  echo $sql;  mysql_query($sql);`.  (Note that the code you posted includes "`// does ...`" as part of the SQL text. MySQL will reject that with a syntax error.)

Comment: @AJReading, my column is configured as Double. I tried your solution (after editing) with no luck

Answer (score 0):

When payment_amt is type integer try floor($payment_amt*100)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the field `payment_amt` has a type of `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` in your database. It is likely `INT` or some other integer at this point.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the integer portion of isn't being stored. MySQL will accept `'100.34'` for insert into an `INTEGER` column, doing the appropriate conversion (losing the .34 and offering a "data truncated" warning, but the insert will succeed.) Also, `DECIMAL(m,n)` datatype is particularly suited to storing numeric values with a fixed number of decimal places (e.g. payment amounts in dollars and cents).

Comment: I changed column to Double. Same issue. Now it record : 0. Before, yes as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes to the field and try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO al_paypal
(item_name,item_number,payment_status,payment_amt,txn_id,payer_email,custom,commerce_id)
       VALUES (
       '". $item_name ."',
       '". $item_number ."', 
       '". $payment_status ."',
        ". $payment_amt .",
       '". $txn_id ."',
       '". $payer_email ."',
       '". $custom ."',
       '". $commerce_id ."'
        )") or die(mysql_error());
```

Remove `// does not record if amount has decimals`

Comment: @user3371049 Could put the rest of the code in this code?

Comment: @user3371049 I edited the post and put `or die (mysql_error());` to know what is in error.

Comment: I added some code in my original post, with result of my different tries. Talk to you tomorrow.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for your help all. See the beginning of my original post at top.